# Javascript's Bind implementation?

Tags: javascript, bind

Since `bind` is not a cross browser (*old ones*) function , there is a polyfill for it : ( *from John Resig's book*)

```
/*1*/       Function.prototype.bind = function ()
/*2*/       {
/*3*/           var fn = this,
/*4*/               args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
/*5*/               object = args.shift();
/*6*/           return function ()
/*7*/           {
/*8*/               return fn.apply(object,
/*9*/                   args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
/*10*/           };
/*11*/       };
```

But I don't understand why do we need `arguments` at line `#9`.

I mean :

If I have this object :

```
var foo = {
    x: 3
}
```

And I have this function :

```
var bar = function(p,b){

    console.log(this.x+'        '+p+'   '+b);
}
```

So  , if I want `bar` to run in the `foo` context  , **with parameters** - All I need to do is :

```
 var boundFunc = bar.bind(foo,1,2)
 boundFunc ()...
```

So When I run `var.bind(foo,1,2)` the `arguments` is `[object Object],1,2`.

Those arguments are saved at line #4.

Great.

Now  , the `bind` function returns its own closured function :

```
function ()
    {
        return fn.apply(object,
            args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    }
```

**Question**

Why do we need `arguments` here ? it seems that they are for something like :

```
var boundFunc = bar.bind(foo,1,2)
boundFunc (more1,more2....) //<----- ??
```

Am I missing something ?

Oonce I set the first `var boundFunc = bar.bind(foo,1,2)` , I already declared the parameters. why do we need them twice ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two places you can pass in arguments to the bound function:

1) When you call bind (the first `arguments`). These are always applied to the bound function when it is called.

2) When you call the bound function (the second `arguments`). These are the "more1, more2" that you mention. These change depending on what is provided when the bound argument is called.

Line 9 is combining the original bound arguments with the supplied extra arguments.

I guess the concept you might be confused about is that you don't have to bind ALL arguments initially - you can bind just the context object, or you can bind the first one argument as well but have callers of the bound function supply the rest. For example:

```
function sum() {
 var _sum = 0
 for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length ; i++) {
     _sum += arguments[i];
 }
 return _sum;
}
var sum_plus_two = sum.bind({},2);
sum_plus_two(5,7) == 14;
```

Answer (score 4):

`.bind` also serves as [**partial application**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) solution. Event handlers might be the best example:

```
var handler = function(data, event) { };

element.addEventListener('click', handler.bind(null, someData));
```

If the arguments from the actual function call wouldn't be passed on, you couldn't access the event object.

Comment: Event is the firstarg imho

Comment: But we already bound a value as first argument (`someData`). So when the event handler will be called and the event object is passed, the bound function will receive it as second argument. If you haven't read the partial application article yet, do it, it should make things more clear.