# Implementation of Function.prototype.bind

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is this implementation of JavaScript's Function.prototype.bind more or less correct?

```
Function.prototype.bindTemp = function () {

    const fn = this;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
    const ctx = args[0];
    args = args.slice(1);

    return function () {
        return fn.apply(ctx, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)));
    }

};
```

anything obviously wrong or missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the main idea, but if you look closely enough (at [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.bind)) there are some points that are rather less correct:

- `bind` should immediately throw a `TypeError` when not called upon a function
- `bind.length` should be `1`
- the bound functions should not rely on the original to have an `.apply` method
- the bound functions should not have a `.prototype` property
- the bound functions should construct an instance of the same type as the original when invoked with `new`<sup>1</sup>
- the bound functions should have the same prototype as the original<sup>2</sup>
- the bound functions should have a `.length` that equals the arity of the original minus the number of bound arguments<sup>3</sup>
- the bound functions should have a `.name` that contains the name of the original<sup>3</sup>

You'll find a [better polyfill at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill).

<sub>1: This cannot reliably distinguished prior to ES6. And to be pedantic, the bound functions should only be constructible at all if the original is as well.

2: This only became relevant as of ES6.

3: This can only be implemented with some kind of `eval` magic prior to ES6.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

As bind was not always cross browser, there was a polyfill for it, and it's mentioned in this question as well: [Javascript's Bind implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103354/javascripts-bind-implementation)

```
/*1*/       Function.prototype.bind = function ()
/*2*/       {
/*3*/           var fn = this,
/*4*/               args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
/*5*/               object = args.shift();
/*6*/           return function ()
/*7*/           {
/*8*/               return fn.apply(object,
/*9*/                   args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
/*10*/           };
/*11*/       };
```

The implementation (from John Resig's book) is the same as yours (nearly), so there shouldn't be anything wrong.

**EDIT**:

Returning a function created with `() =>` instead of `function()` would avoid you storing the `this` variable into `fn`, as arrow functions bind the `this` above.

Comment: Just because a function was written by John Resig doesn't make it correct :-)